# Can we build Flutter apps for Samsung TV?

Tags: flutter, dart, television

Can we make Flutter apps for Samsung TV? If yes, from where to start, I mean is there any documentation available? If any demo flutter app for Samsung TV available on internet please share the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, no.

There is no support for any of the TV-OSs or Watch OSs or any of those peripheral devices. It's iOS, Android, Desktop apps for various desktops and the web.

Whether there are any unsupported hacks that might work with specific version of Flutter and a specific version of Samsung TVs I don't know. Maybe.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/flutter-tizen/flutter-tizen

There is a project developed by Samsung's Tizen team and it works on Samsung TVs running Tizen 6.0 or above.

Answer (score 2):

We can do with the help of Tizen.

Samsung Smart TVs support Flutter framework since Tizen 6.0

In order to develop a Flutter application for Samsung Smart TVs, you must set up Flutter application development environment. A Flutter application project must be created through Flutter-Tizen. You can refer to the following guides for this settings.
Flutter-Tizen installation documents
Supported Flutter-Tizen plugins

[For More information](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/native/flutter.html)